# paint weight errors?

Tags: weight-painting, rigify

**Okay need help or opinions from senior artist or more experience one**. I using rigify and already parent with automated weights to my mode, but the problem is there's certain area of the face that moving too when I played with mouth controller but I can seem to edit the edit the influence of effective area on paint weight.

**sorry for broken english on my side but here I will include file and a picture as you ref.

[image: as you can see here is the pic of the model in weight paint and I already click on the controller but not even a little bit has color on it, all blue]

[image: second pic shown that I can moved model properly but it wasn't perfect, there were part that need to add more paints]

so, i wondered what happened here, what is the reason that i can't see the painted area? do you guys get it the question, this is so confusing.

**how do I included the file here? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z5oKrHH9KeEXnN3oO2wl0DuZ-pnz3olM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello it looks like the host platform doesn't work

Comment: How do i fix it?

Comment: you can try https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: if i put the file there, it would be fix? or how does it work? never use it, btw thank you so much for the help. very much appreciate it

Comment: it's just a way to share the file, the link you gave doesn't work, then people can upload your file and test it

Comment: there's an error when i want to drag the file there, check the link again.

Comment: for the moment all these parts are not part of the rest of the body (called baju), do you plan to keep them apart? If you keep them apart you can parent these parts to the bone called DEF-spine.006